# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when redirecting to non-www HTTPS in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all calls to non-www HTTPS on my website and have the following code in my `.htaccess` file in Laravel besides the auto generated stuff:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

and the following routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('build.index');
});

Auth::routes();

// Profile
Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@show')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');

// Build
Route::get('/builds', 'BuildsController@index')->name('build.index');
Route::get('/builds/{hunter}', 'BuildsController@hunter')->name('build.hunter');
Route::get('/build/create', 'BuildsController@create')->name('build.create');
Route::post('/build', 'BuildsController@store')->name('build.store');
Route::get('/build/{build}/edit', 'BuildsController@edit')->name('build.edit');
Route::put('/build/{build}', 'BuildsController@update')->name('build.update');
Route::get('/build/{build}/{hunter?}/{title?}', 'BuildsController@show')->name('build.show');

// Skill trees
Route::get('/planner/{encryption}', 'PlannerController@show');
Route::get('/planner', 'PlannerController@index');

Route::post('/rate/{build}/{rating}', 'RatingsController@store');
Route::put('/rate/{build}/{rating}', 'RatingsController@update');
Route::delete('/rate/{build}', 'RatingsController@destroy');

Route::post('/comment', 'CommentsController@store');
```

Does someone know what is causing this redirect loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to redirect all requests to `http://example.com`, `http://www.example.com`, and `https://www.example.com` to `https://example.com`. In order to do that, this is the proper way to do it in your access file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Comment: I tried this and still getting the redirects, even tried directly in the Apache .conf file and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

About 1-st question (the reason of too many redirection):

Redirects are comes from 3-rd line of your .htaccess
Probably you've typed non-"www" URL and it wanted to redirect that to the page (https://example.com/... in your case) which is also not have "www" prefix.
So it falls in loop, and after 20 times it throwed an error.

1. Instead you can try these ways:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

This will redirect all non-https requests to the with-https.

2. If you want to redirect all non-www requests to the with-www, then use this:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?your.domain$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.your.domain/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

3. If you want to mix these 2 conditions into one, you can do that via regex:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

This will redirect all these requests

```
 http://your.domain/...
 http://www.your.domain/...
 https://your.domain/...
```

to the "https://www.your.domain/..."

**Note:** don't forget to write this right before your these 3 ways. for example like this:

```
 # actually this can be the answer for your 2-nd question
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?(.*) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S. Routes are not necessary for this question

Comment: I tried your first solution and I still get the error. In the "Network" tab I can see that it just keeps refreshing same https page for some reason.