# how to redirect http to https:www.domain.com in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect http to

> https://www.example.com

in laravel 5.2

trying to do it using middlware Please see code

```
In karnel.php

\App\Http\Middleware\HttpsProtocol::class,
```

middlware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)

{
   $url = 'https://www.example.com';
    if (!$request->secure()) {
        return redirect()->secure($url);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

but getting error

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

And when try to do it using .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# require SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

it will redirect to

> https://www.www.example.com

What i want is if anyone type domain.com then it will automatically redirect to

> https://www/example.com

in laravel 5.2

Comment: You are probably looping through the handle method why causing amounts of redirects

Comment: Follow to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58209607/err-too-many-redirects-when-redirecting-to-non-www-https-in-laravel/58210357#58210357) (actually the last part). I think that's what you want

Comment: See this link:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28402726/laravel-5-redirect-to-https)